# How to set TableRow width to max in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-tablelayout, tablerow

I have a table defined in .xml file but rows and headers have to be added dynamically. I have a problem with fill width with table row on horizontal and vertical orientation. I have tried stretchColumns parameter but it did not help. What is the best way to do it?

```
            table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.testList);

        TableRow headerRow  = new TableRow(this);

        JSONObject obj;

        obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());

        JSONArray records = obj.getJSONArray("tests");

        ArrayList<String> headers = new ArrayList<>();
        headers.add("Header 1");
        headers.add("Header 2");
        headers.add("Header 3");
        headers.add("Header 4");
        headers.add("Header 5");

        for(int i = 0; i < headers.size(); i++) {
            TextView header = new TextView(this);
            header.setText(headers.get(i));
            header.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            header.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(24, 116, 205));
            header.setPadding(15, 15, 15, 15);
            header.setTextSize(20);
            header.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);

            header.setMaxLines(1);
            headerRow.addView(header);

        }

        table.addView(headerRow);
```

and xml

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content">


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/testList"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content">

            </TableLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>

</GridLayout>
```

Comment: since your table is inside scrollview, it has no limit of width and height. So there is no way to determine, which is the *max* width. You can only set it manually

Comment: @VladMatvienko so how to do it without scroll views?

Comment: I didn't say that you need to do it without scrollView. You need to decide, which width is *max* for you. Is it some exact value, like 100dp, or it is the screen width, or what?

Comment: @VladMatvienko ok but what if I want to fill all screen width and I have devices with different resolution?

Comment: You can get screen width at runtime, and set View width at runtime as well

Comment: @VladMatvienko ok, I know how to get screen width but could you give an exampe how to combine it with vertical and horizontal scroll view and tablelayout and tablerow?

Comment: you need to set the exact width to you table row. https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20set%20view%20width%20programmatically

Answer (score 5):

Try this way. The following will make sure `TableRow` is aligned to full available width.

After base components, put your `TableLayout` in XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainLL"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now in your logic, you can add according to the number of items from response. This should be in a for loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < leftComponent.size(); i++) 
    {
            //Table Layout parameters
            TableRow.LayoutParams textViewParam = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,1.0f);
            TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.fenceTableLayout);
            TableRow trHead = new TableRow(context);
            LayoutParams tableRowParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            trHead.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);

            TextView nameHead = new TextView(context);
            nameHead.setText(leftComponent[i]);
            nameHead.setLayoutParams(textViewParam);
            nameHead.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            trHead.addView(nameHead);

            TextView detailHead = new TextView(context);
            detailHead.setText(rightComponent[i]);
            detailHead.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            detailHead.setLayoutParams(textViewParam);

            trHead.addView(detailHead);
            tableLayout.addView(trHead);

    }
```

You may need to customize according to your requirement.

Comment: thank you. The Java code saved me from my deadline :)